# How do I call a COM-function with a _variant_t parameter (type "long")?

Tags: c#, com, interop, com-interop

I want to port a certain function call to C#. The two lines are as follows:

```
    m_pBrowserApp->get_Document(&pVoid);
    m_pLayoutAnalyzer->Analyze4(pVoid, _variant_t(5L));
```

`m_pBrowserApp` is the ActiveX browser object and `pVoid` is its document property. I can get that by calling `WebBrowserBase.ActiveXInstance.Document`. However, I have no idea how to create a `_variant_t(5L)` in C#. Since the call is not a VT_BYREF, it "should just work" by calling it like this:

```
    ILayoutAnalyzer2 vips = new LayoutAnalyzer2();
    vips.Initialize(0);
    SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1 axBrowser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1)this.webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;
    var doc = axBrowser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;

    vips.Analyze4(doc, (Object)5L); // fails with HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH)
```

But it doesn't. It fails with a `DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH` error.
I'm pretty sure the Document property is valid. So the question remains: How to I properly pass a long wrapped in a variant via interop?

Comment: Have you tried `vips.Analyze4(doc, 5L);`? Casting it to an object should lead to `VT_BYREF | VT_UNKNOWN`, as far as I remember. So it must fail...

Comment: I have. [Same result.](http://i.snag.gy/7LfV9.jpg)

Comment: That's it! Wonderful! Can you post that again as an answer so I can mark it, @HansPassant ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variants go back to the mid 1990s, a time when longs were consider long for having 32 bits.  This is just a few years after the first 32-bit operating systems became available, an integer was still 16 bits in VB6 for example.  Not so in C# and .NET in general, a 32-bit programming environment by design that never had to deal with 16-bit back-compat.  So use a C# int, not a long.

Drop the L from the literal.

Comment: Back then 64 bit longs were "long longs". Oh, the pain.